# Resources for Algebraic Machine Learning

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, machine-learning

I have humble, around-undergraduate level understanding of mathematics. I enjoy abstract algebra and statistics the most. After stumbling upon Michael Izbicki's paper [Algebraic classifiers](https://izbicki.me/public/papers/icml2013-algebraic-classifiers.pdf), I decided that I wanted to understand this topic more.

I am looking for resources to study Algebraic Machine Learning. A suitable reference should be self-contained, including the relevant category theory background required for this field. It should also explicitly address the fundamental categorical aspects of algebraic machine learning, such as

1. Why do Markov Fields form a monoid and how does it look like?
2. Do Bayes Networks form a monoid?
3. Do Neural Nets form a monoid?

Can anyone recommend a text or an appropriate media resource?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. You should know it's not very welcome to post several questions at the same time here. If you need a category theory book, I'd recommend Category theory for working mathematicians by Mac Lane. Unfortunately I can't help you with the rest.You should only ask specific questions and ask them one by one to better fit the fornat.

Comment: This sort of question, which i might call a "shotgun" question, is not a good fit for our format.  Moreover, it has more to do with you choosing something to learn rather than an actual math question, and that is another strike against it.  If you have a particular passage that asserts some structure is a monoid and you're stuck seeing that, then maybe you want to focus on that.

Comment: Personally I think this idea to explode out to category theory instantly is hasty. If you are not yet comfortable with monoids, I would suggest finding some easy introduction to monoids and groups. I think Jacobson's "Basic Algebra" volumes cover this at a level that would suit you, and they are cheap and easy to find.

Comment: I reworded this so that it falls more neatly within our site guidelines. I believe this also more accurately expresses that author's intent. (Correct me if I'm wrong, OP.)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Yes, this is definitely better. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, in case you don't get a better answer, you may find the citations and references for this paper on [its Semantics scholar page](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Algebraic-classifiers%3A-a-generic-approach-to-fast-Izbicki/168574132d5eabbfeca7f5ee7cdb4daa1e90bb10?navId=citing-papers) to be a good starting point.